# I have a Acer K272HUL that goes grayscale periodically

Tags: display, lcd

I have a Acer K272HUL that goes grayscale periodically.  In more detail, videos and moving graphics on the screen are in color and everything else on the screen goes shades of gray.

Found more info at

http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2443378/monitor-displayport-inactive-windows-grayscale-gtx760.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the monitor has a "detect video" feature in the menu.  Turn this off.